# Which algorithm can I use to find the next to shortest path in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to find the next shortest path between 2 vertices in a graph and the path has a positive cost.The next shortest path is allowed to share edges of the shortest path .Which algorithm can I use?

Comment: i.e. not the shortest path itself, but the shortest path excluding the actual shortest path?

Comment: I assume you are asking about shortest path between two fixed vertices. What type of graph? DAG with positive edges?

Comment: Presumably you mean the *"shortest path between two given Nodes on the graph"* and not *"the shortest path visiting all the Nodes of the graph"*, because that is a LITTLE bit harder.

Comment: Can the second shortest path share common edges with the shortest path, or only common nodes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I doubt this is optimal in terms of running time but:

1. Use Dijkstra's algorithm on graph G to get path P
2. For all edges E in path P:
3. -- If G - E is not connected, continue for next edge (go to 2)
4. -- Use Dijkstra's algorithm on G - E to find path X_i
5. -- If length of current X_i is shorter than all other X_i, save it
6. The X_i at the end of the for loop is the second shortest path

The second-shortest path can't go through all edges in P, but it could go through all but one of them, potentially.  I assume by "second-shortest" that you don't use edges more than once, otherwise the second-shortest path could contain P.

Comment: Couldn't G-E result in two, disjoint graphs?  I think your algorithm will work in a completely connected graph, but what happens if there is only one edge which connects to a node to the rest of the graph?

Comment: OP does not say wha type of graph this is. If it's undirected and/or cyclic, second shortest path could contain shortest path.

Comment: Note that this only works if the next shortest path is allowed to share common edges with the shortest path.

Comment: @David - if this the case, then that particular edge is necessary to have any path through the graph at all.

Comment: @Spintheblack: but if you remove "that patricular edge" Dijkstra's algorithm will not finish.

Comment: I assumed second-shortest path that does not use any edge more than once, but if you are allowed to duplicated edges, this won't work for cyclic graphs.

Comment: @David - Not clear why -   The priority queue will empty without hitting the final node and an infinite length will be returned for that iteration

Comment: @tkerwin - I don't think this algorithm allows duplicate edges.  Each of the iterations is run over a subgraph of the original with the same constraints as Dijsktras.

Comment: @spinetheblack, good point, you could fix this by removing duplicate edges on path P, but it depends what kind of result you want.

Comment: I think David is referring to a bridge, but it still works -- Dijkstra will terminate.  This is equivalent to the method of finding the second shortest minimum spanning tree, though in suboptimal time.

Comment: I think there is bug in the algorithm: you can have a second shortest path that contains the shortest path even without using the same edge twice. Consider the graph: V={s,m,t},  E={s-->m, m-->t, m-->m}, and weight function that assigns 1 to all edges. The shortest path between s and t is: s-->m-->t and the second shortest path is: s-->m-->m-->t. Your algorithm won't catch it.

Comment: @Guy As I remember, a path cannot pass the same vertex twice by definition.

Comment: As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_and_path) shows, whether path can "pass the same vertex" depends on the definition. IMHO in the daily life problem, the graph is probably one *simple graph* because it seems weird to loop at one middle point when we want to get to one destination (no loop) and only considers one candidate path between each vertex (not one multigraph). Then the case in Guy's example is impossible.

Answer (score 17):

Use the K-shortest path algorithm, where k=2 for you, some sample reference:

Finding the k shortest paths.
D. Eppstein.
35th IEEE Symp. Foundations of Comp. Sci., Santa Fe, 1994, pp. 154-165.
Tech. Rep. 94-26, ICS, UCI, 1994.
SIAM J. Computing 28(2):652-673, 1998.

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-TR-94-26.pdf

Comment: The algorithm is actually quite simple, no need to read 20 pages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing#Algorithm

Comment: The wikipedia link may give one skeleton of the algorithm. But it doesn't show how `u` is updated which seems to be significant.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use Floyd-Warshall's algorithm to find all pairs shortest path and then testing all intermediate edges is a sure - but perhaps not optimal way - to solve this.  Here's a great explanation 
http://hatemabdelghani.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/second-shortest-path/

Comment: The link finds second shortest paths between any vertices. To find second shortest path between given two vertices `s` and `t`, use Dijkstra algorithm to compute the shortest path from `s` to each vertex and compute the shortest path from each vertex to `t`.

Comment: It seems like the link you've provided implicitly assumes that there is a unique shortest path. You might need to modify it if there are multiple paths that are equally short (depending on the formulation of the problem, of course).

Answer (score 4):

**This is assuming you can reuse edges and nodes:**

A straightfoward solution is do make an extension of the Djikstra Algorithm.

- Instead of storing for each node the smallest cost and its respective parent, store the two smallest costs (and their respective parents).
- For the priority queue, intead of storing nodes, store (node, i) pairs, so you know wether to use the 1st or 2nd path during propagation.
- Take care during the propagation phases to keep the multiple path values correctly updated.

(I might be missing some important details but the basic idea is here...)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path, P.

You then can view this problem as a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) (where the constraint is "the shortest path which is not P") and, use a [backtracking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to find the shortest path which is not the shortest path you already found.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this works.  If you use a backtracking algorithm, you potentially are evaluating a much large portion of the graph - how does the initial path help you ; there may be cases when the 2nd shortest path is not a subpath of the first.

Comment: The initial, shortest path is part of the constraints:  you want the shortest path which is has not already been taken.

Comment: You've constrained a single path amongst a possibility of an exponential number of paths - I don't see how this is different from a brute force approach or, if we're looking for a disjoint path, different from the answers below.

Comment: You're right, I've turned this into a search problem (whose time complexity could be exponential in the number of edges); but that does not make my solution wrong.  Improvements could be made by propagating the constraints, or something else.  This solution may not be different than the others, but I think I posted a solution first.

Comment: Sorry - if that came across as 'you're answer is wrong', it wasn't meant to, my quibble was over its generality. My thought was that very general algorithms such as backtracking and other 'enumeration' type algorithms (all paths) can be applied to most graph related problems but with worst case exponential time when there are specific algorithms that do much better. These can be conceptualized in a similar way - Dijsktra's algorithm can be thought of using the triangle inequality, for example.

Comment: @spintheblack: No worries.:)  I understand your intent.  My solution does introduce with it poor time/space complexity; but I also think it's a good idea to give the asker a breadth of options and let the votes sort the value of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes you are looking for the edge-disjoint second shortest path, which means the second shortest path cannot share any common edges with the shortest path.

Recall that the [maximum flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) in a network between two nodes `A` and `B` gives you the number of edge-disjoint paths between those two nodes. Also recall that algorithms such as [Edmonds-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) work by sending flow over a shortest path at each step.

So this problem only has a solution if the max flow between your two nodes is > 1, where each edge has a capacity of 1. If it does, find two augmenting paths as described in the Edmonds-Karp algorithm, and the second one is your second shortest.

See [this problem](http://acm.sgu.ru/problem.php?contest=0&problem=185) and [this solution](http://acmicpc.org.cn/wiki/index.php?title=SGU_185_Solution) to it (The description is in Chinese. I can't translate it, and babelfish can't really do it either, but won't admit it. The code is easy to follow though) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

When you prefer a practical solution to an academic one, here is one.

I solved this by setting a penalty to the shortest path edges and running the search again.

E.g. shortest path has length 1000, penalty is 10%, so I search for a 2nd shortest path with 1000<=length<=1100.

In the worst case I find the previous shortest path.
In the best case I find a disjunct path with the same length.
In most cases I find a path sharing some locally optimal subpaths.

Increasing the penalty forces the algorithm to find alternative routes, while decreasing makes it sharing tolerant.

When I find the 2nd shortest path, I have to subtract the sum of penalties on shared edges from the computed length to get the real length.

For k-th shortest path I set the penalty to all edges used in previous k-1 shortest paths.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [k shortest path routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing). Basically, run modified Dijkstra, but instead of keeping edges on the min-heap, keep all paths found so far.

I prefer working code since the devil is always in the detail:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Iterable<Integer>[] kShortestPaths(EdgeWeightedDigraph g, int s, int t, int k) {
    if (k <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("k must be positive");

    boolean[] visited = new boolean[g.V()];
    int[] count = new int[g.V()];
    MinPQ<Map.Entry<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>, Queue<Integer>>> heap = new MinPQ<>(
            comparingDouble(e -> e.getKey().getValue())
    );
    Queue<Integer>[] p = (Queue<Integer>[]) new Queue<?>[k];

    heap.insert(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(s, 0.0d), new Queue<>()));

    int i = 0;
    while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
        Map.Entry<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>, Queue<Integer>> node = heap.delMin();
        Integer u = node.getKey().getKey();
        if (count[u] >= k) break;

        Queue<Integer> pathU = node.getValue();
        visited[u] = true;
        pathU.enqueue(u);

        if (u == t) {
            p[i] = new Queue<>();
            for (int w : pathU) {
                p[i].enqueue(w);
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (count[u]++ <= k) {
            double costU = node.getKey().getValue();
            for (DirectedEdge e : g.adj(u)) {
                int v = e.to();
                if (!visited[v]) {
                    Queue<Integer> pathV = new Queue<>();
                    for (int w : pathU) {
                        pathV.enqueue(w);
                    }
                    heap.insert(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(v, e.weight() + costU), pathV));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

`EdgeWeightedDigraph` and `MinPQ` are from https://github.com/kevin-wayne/algs4.

[image]

k = 1, p = [0, 1, 2, 3]

k = 2, p = [0, 4, 5, 3]