# Multiple shortest paths using Dijkstra

Tags: java, android, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I'm currently using Dijkstra Algorithm for find shortest path. This algorithm gives me best shortest path but I want to have 2 or more paths. How can I achieve this?

Algorithm is as follows:

```
public class Dijkstra
{
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
    {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
        if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
            vertexQueue.remove(v);

            v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
            v.previous = u;
            vertexQueue.add(v);
        }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 2 or more paths? If the shortest path has length `x`, do you want *all* paths with length `x`? Or do you want the 2 shortest paths (where the second one might be `>x`)?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing

Comment: http://www.mat.uc.pt/~eqvm/OPP/KSPP/KSPP.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971850/which-algorithm-can-i-use-to-find-the-next-to-shortest-path-in-a-graph

Comment: Your code is broken: `vertexQueue` can only contain `source`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Yen top K shortest path algorithm which uses Dijkstra to calculate the optimal path, after that it uses Dijkstra to calculate the second most optimal path etc.

I found a Java implementation for that here: https://github.com/yan-qi/k-shortest-paths-java-version/tree/master/src/main/java/edu/asu/emit/algorithm/graph/shortestpaths

Hope that helps