# Find SECOND shortest path in directred graph

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra

I need a way to find second shortest path in directed graph, on top of that second shortest path cannot include the shortest path entirely. I am aware of dijkstra algoritm, but I am unable to figure out a simple way on how to change that algorithm to give me a second shortest path in a reasonable amount of time. Algorithm, sudo-code or c++ example, one of the three will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which algorithm can I use to find the next to shortest path in a graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971850/which-algorithm-can-i-use-to-find-the-next-to-shortest-path-in-a-graph)

Comment: The problem you are going to have is proving that you have the 2nd shortest path, you might have found the 3rd, 4th or other path.

Comment: Not an algorithm expert but what about successively removing one link connection from *the shortest path* and then find the new shortest path with that link missing. Then compare all your new shortest paths?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following is correct and works, but its just an idea....

The second shortest path has at least one edge different from the shortest path. If no node is visited twice, this also means, that there is at least one edge in the shortest path that is not used by the second shortest path.

If that is correct, you could first search the shortest path. Then for each edge in the shortest path: set its weight to infinity (ie exclude it from the graph) and search for the shortest path in the resulting graph. The shortest path among those should be the second shortest in the original graph.