# Finding second shortest path in a graph(With Backtracking)

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I found a problem in LightOJ where the problem was to find the second shortest path in a graph from node 1 to node n(There are n nodes in the graph marked from 1 to n). Now, the problem stated that I can backtrack to find a second shortest path. One of the sample cases is like this:

- Edge from node 1 to 2, cost 100.
- Edge from node 2 to 3, cost 300.
- Edge from node 1 to 3, cost 50.

The answer for this test is 150, for this path 1->2->1->3.
I am aware of Dijkstra algorithm. But I could not find anything on how to do this. I am sorry if this is and old topic but I when I googled it I could not find anything.

Update: I read this question. [Which algorithm can I use to find the next to shortest path in a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971850/which-algorithm-can-i-use-to-find-the-next-to-shortest-path-in-a-graph)
My question is different from it because in this problem, I can use an edge twice. I am going from node 1 to 2 once, then coming back to 1. This using edge 1->2 twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which algorithm can I use to find the next to shortest path in a graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971850/which-algorithm-can-i-use-to-find-the-next-to-shortest-path-in-a-graph)

Comment: You'll need to keep a vector of the costs of the cheapest two paths as you traverse the graph.

Comment: I saw that question. But I need an algorithm to that can backtrack @500-InternalServerError

Comment: You can find all possible paths between two nodes by iterative deepening , maintaining their cost . These costs can be sorted and second in the list can be returned.

Comment: Any pseudocode or algo would help. Plus the problem was under Dijkstra. So I'm looking for a solution which uses Dijkstra algorithm

Comment: Assuming you are talking about undirected graphs, 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 should have the total cost of 250, no?

Comment: The graph is undirected, Yes. And I thought that too. But then I thought that the cost of edge 1->2 was already added, then no need to add it again. (Yes. I know it sounds stupid, But I couldn't find any other way to explain the solution.)

Answer (score 3):

I think this might work:

Maintain two arrays: `shortest[i]` and `sec_shortest[i]` which denote the shortest and the second shortest path lengths of vertex `i` respectively.

Now, all you need is to modify the method in the `update` part of Dijkstra's algorithm in a slightly different way:

```
for v in adj(u):
    if shortest[u] + cost(u, v) < shortest[v]:
        sec_shortest[v] = shortest[v]
        shortest[v] = shortest[u] + cost(u, v)
    else if shortest[u] + cost(u, v) < sec_shortest[v]:
            sec_shortest[v] = shortest[u] + cost(u, v)
```

In the end, `sec_shortest[i]` will contain the second shortest path length from the fixed source to vertex `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution for this. First find the shortest path. Let's say this shortest path has k edges.

Have a loop from i = 1 to k, then each time set the value of the i_th edge of path to infinity. After this, run the shortest path algorithm. And return the minimum over all k new shortest paths that you get.

Note that each you set exactly one edge to infinity. Why does this work? Because you will get a shortest path that differs from the original at in one edge.

However, your question is a little ambiguous because second shortest path means that the next shortest path  that has a strictly higher cost. Or it could mean just find two different shortest paths. I assumed the latter case in my answer.